# localhost doesn't work on my mac?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I'm brand new to all this so please cut me a little slack. I'm trying to learn PHP but I'm getting hung up on the beginning of the lessons where I'm setting up Apache.

I should apparently be able to go to localhost in my browser and see "It works!" but I don't, I see this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

The directions I followed were very similar to this: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083 just in a video. And I didn't to the perl part, but I think that's optional.

I can't figure out why I can't see anything at localhost (127.0.0.1 returns the same thing) despite nearly two hours of googling and fiddling. Please some one tell me you know what's going on.

I'm happy to provide any clarifications. At this point I'm not even sure what's important.

Comment: Are you sure your Apache/MySql (or any local php server host) is up ?

Comment: I think so. If I do `pr aux | grep httpd` I get 
`_www           40931   0.0  0.0  2454844   1400   ??  S    11:15AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www           40929   0.0  0.0  2454844   1392   ??  S    11:15AM   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root           40927   0.0  0.1  2454844   7064   ??  Ss   11:15AM   0:00.23 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`
 
  Unless that's not what you meant by "up"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newbie better download and install XAMPP for Mac. The default apache is little bit complicated in mac.

[Downlaod from here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go. Hopefully it'll be in line with the rest of the course I'm watching. Will any of the settings I've already set screw that up at all?

Comment: Ok, I was sort of expecting some sort of instructions to come with this. I installed it but now what? The localhost still doesn't work, and when I try to start the "Apache Web Server" through "Manage Servers" it goes orange for a bit and then turns back to red and "stopped."

Comment: @user3684607 You have to stop the default apache by `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` and then start your XAMPP apache.

Answer (score 0):

Either MAMP or XAMPP will be way less complicated

http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ is for MAMP but you have to have a MAC OS X 10.6.6